# Precalculate Result of A*

Tags: algorithm, search, a-star, sliding-tile-puzzle

Currently learning about the `A*` search algorithm and using it to find the quickest solution to the `N-Puzzle`. For some random seed of the initial starting state, the puzzle may be unsolvable which would result in extremely long wait times until the algorithm has search the entire search-space and determined there is not solution to the give start state.

I was wondering if there is a method of precalculating whether the `A*` algorithm will fail to avoid such a scenario. I've read a bit about how it is possible but can't find a direct answer as to a method in which to do it.

Any guidance or options are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think A* does not offer you a mechanism to know whether or not a problem is solvable. Specifically for `N-Puzzle`, I think this could help you to check if it can be solved or not:

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-instance-8-puzzle-solvable/

It seems that if you are in a state where you have an odd amount inversion, you know for sure the problem for that permutation is infeasible.

Answer (score 2):

For the N-puzzle specifically, there are only two possible parities, so you just need to check which parity the current puzzle is.

There is an in-depth explanation on how to do this on the [math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293527/how-to-check-if-a-8-puzzle-is-solvable)

For general A* problems, no, there is no way to pre-compute if the graph is solvable.